# Try runtime failed to generate compact proof: TrieError(InvalidStateRoot

Tags: try-runtime

In a recent upgrade of substrate try-runtime begun to return errors and fault which could previously be ignored started to catch my attention.

What could be possible sources of this problem:

> [2023-10-30T00:48:19Z ERROR try-runtime::cli] failed to generate compact proof: TrieError(InvalidStateRoot(0xf5a724024e2b3ff6914d9d191f1d2794bd76413a5f298aa5e8ebbe7fbaaec820))

```
[2023-10-30T00:48:16Z INFO  remote-ext] Loading snapshot from "snapshots/eden"
✅ Loaded snapshot (0.70s)
[2023-10-30T00:48:17Z INFO  remote-ext] initialized state externalities with storage root 0x953ab4b56c3cbb2d920e4d8fbf4d0c8303159c267cd05c6b9149ae579a055737 and state_version V0
[2023-10-30T00:48:17Z INFO  try-runtime::cli] Original runtime [Name: RuntimeString::Owned("nodle-para")] [Version: 23] [Code hash: 0xae58...e0f9]
[2023-10-30T00:48:17Z INFO  try-runtime::cli] New runtime      [Name: RuntimeString::Owned("nodle-para")] [Version: 25] [Code hash: 0x782b...0990]
[2023-10-30T00:48:17Z INFO  try_runtime_core::commands::on_runtime_upgrade]  Running TryRuntime_on_runtime_upgrade with checks: PreAndPost
[2023-10-30T00:48:19Z INFO  runtime::frame-support] ⚠️ PolkadotXcm declares internal migrations (which *might* execute). On-chain `StorageVersion(1)` vs current storage version `StorageVersion(1)`
[2023-10-30T00:48:19Z INFO  try_runtime_core::commands::on_runtime_upgrade]  TryRuntime_on_runtime_upgrade succeeded! Running it again without checks for weight measurements.
[2023-10-30T00:48:19Z INFO  runtime::frame-support] ⚠️ PolkadotXcm declares internal migrations (which *might* execute). On-chain `StorageVersion(1)` vs current storage version `StorageVersion(1)`
[2023-10-30T00:48:19Z ERROR try-runtime::cli] failed to generate compact proof: TrieError(InvalidStateRoot(0xf5a724024e2b3ff6914d9d191f1d2794bd76413a5f298aa5e8ebbe7fbaaec820))
[2023-10-30T00:48:19Z INFO  try-runtime::cli] PoV size (zstd-compressed compact proof): 10 B. For parachains, it's your responsibility to verify that a PoV of this size fits within any relaychain constraints.
[2023-10-30T00:48:19Z INFO  try-runtime::cli] Consumed ref_time: 0s (0.00% of max 0.5s)
[2023-10-30T00:48:19Z INFO  try-runtime::cli] ✅ TryRuntime_on_runtime_upgrade executed without errors or weight safety warnings. Please note this does not guarantee a successful runtime upgrade. Always test your runtime upgrade with recent state, and ensure that the weight usage of your migrations will not drastically differ between testing and actual on-chain execution.
```

The project is a parachain and the above error is generated with *Substrate's programmatic testing framework.* like this:

```
cargo build --release --features try-runtime
~/.cargo/bin/try-runtime --runtime ./target/release/wbuild/runtime-eden/runtime_eden.wasm   on-runtime-upgrade snap -p snapshots/eden
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, it's a bug / limitation with the technique used by try-runtime-cli to generate the compact proof. Tracked here, https://github.com/paritytech/try-runtime-cli/issues/76 I hope to fix it soon.

Comment: This will be fixed in https://github.com/paritytech/try-runtime-cli/pull/77 and released in v0.5.4 today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try-runtime on-runtime-upgrade --help` suggests: "Performing any checks will potentially invalidate the measured PoV/Weight." Suggest running it separately with `--checks=none` to check the POV/Weight.

Comment: I'm also getting the mentioned error, so is it safe to ignore it? why is the error happening?

Comment: @Sebastian suggest that you try again with the latest version of try-runtume-cli. They have just recently addressed some of these issues.

Comment: I'm already using the latest version